# Limiting channel entry results per channel

Tags: channel-entries

Assuming I have this:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="news|tweets" 
    disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks|categories|category_fields" 
    status="open" 
}

    <h2>{title}</h2>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Is there any way I can limit the results of each channel? For example 5 from tweets, 10 from news. I'm assuming not...

Comment: Maybe you can use the query module and write your own query for this?

Comment: @Timo002 yes I think that, or a custom module that extends the core channel entries module.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct. You cannot limit to "X" number from EACH defined channel. You can limit to "X" number from the COMBINED defined  channels using the limit="X" parameter.